# TypeScript no autocomplete on generics, but type is checked

Tags: typescript, autocomplete, typescript-typings, intellisense, typescript-generics

I'm building an abstraction that allows following use, where the passed "generics" like "Step 1" or the nested "Step 1 procedure 1" are type-checked and autocomplete with intellisense.

```
type ProcedureSpec = {
  name: string;
};

type StepSpec = {
  name: string;
  procedures: Readonly<ProcedureSpec[]>;
};

type PipelineSpec = Readonly<{
  name: string;
  slug: string;
  steps: Readonly<StepSpec[]>;
}>;

const spec = {
  name: "Pipeline 1 name",
  slug: "pipeline1Slug",
  steps: [
    {
      name: "Step 1",
      procedures: [
        { name: "Step 1 procedure 1" },
        { name: "Step 1 procedure 2" },
        { name: "Step 1 procedure 3" },
      ],
    },
  ],
} as const satisfies PipelineSpec;

await pipeline<typeof spec>(async (step) => {
  await step<"Step 1">(async (procedure) => {
    await procedure<"Step 1 procedure 1">(async () => {
      console.log("Step 1 procedure 1");
    });
    await procedure<"Step 1 procedure 2">(async () => {
      console.log("Step 1 procedure 2");
    });
    await procedure<"Step 1 procedure 3">(async () => {
      console.log("Step 1 procedure 3");
    });
  });
});
```

My implementation (see below) is type-checked but the autocomplete does not work:

```
export async function pipeline<T extends PipelineSpec>(
  pipelineCb: (
    step: <SName extends T["steps"][number]["name"]>(
      stepCb: <S extends T["steps"][number] = Extract<T["steps"][number], { name: SName }>>(
        procedure: <PName extends S["procedures"][number]["name"]>(
          procedureCb: () => Promise<void>
        ) => Promise<void>
      ) => Promise<void>
    ) => Promise<void>
  ) => Promise<void>
) {
  return await pipelineCb(async (stepCb) => {
    return await stepCb(async (procedureCb) => {
      return await procedureCb();
    });
  });
}
```

[image: Example]

Any idea how to fix that?

Only clue I've found so far is that TypeScript's autocomplete breaks on nested types. But I feel like there should be a way to accomplish this. I am not bound to this exact API. I could imagine passing the string as an actual argument to the functions `step()` and `procedure()`.

Comment: Could you [edit] demonstrate with code where "autocomplete breaks"?  Like, what do you expect to see and where?

Comment: I added an example that shows that type-safety works (second procedure) but no autocomplete (third procedure).

Comment: Screenshots of IDEs are unfortunately not appropriate here. [Please replace/supplement images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)